# Android - deleting characters on button press

Tags: android, button, arraylist

Below is the method I've coded to input numbers for a calculator. The code is fully functional and is error-free.

I'm trying to figure out how I would write a separate method called `backspace` to remove one character at a time from the user input.

To give an example of how `onClick1` works (just to make it crystal clear what I want to do), if I entered `2+4*6` (using buttons; their onClick action linked to `onClick1`), then `textViewCalcHistExp1` would display the text `2+4*6`, and `arrayList` would hold the following values: `[2,+,4,*,6]`.

I want `backspace` to work so that if I clicked the button (linked with the `backspace` method), `textViewCalcHistExp1`'s display would now be `2+4*` and `arrayList` would now hold the following values: `[2,+,4,*]`.

Here is the code:

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
String stringInput = "";
String stringInputWithOp = "";
public String prevCalc = "";

public void onClick1 (View view) {
    TextView textViewCalcHistExp1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCalcHistExp1);
    Button button = (Button) view;
    stringInput = (String) button.getText().toString();


    if (!stringInput.contains("+") && !stringInput.contains("-") && !stringInput.contains("×") && !stringInput.contains("÷")) {
        stringInputWithOp = stringInputWithOp+stringInput;
        if (arrayList.size()>0) {
            arrayList.remove((arrayList.size()-1));
        }
        arrayList.add(stringInputWithOp);
    }
    else {
        arrayList.add(stringInput);
        arrayList.add(stringInput);
        stringInputWithOp="";
    }
    //This version truncates array formatting i.e. entering "2+4*6" would display "2+4*6"
    textViewCalcHistExp1.setText(textViewCalcHistExp1.getText().toString()+stringInput);

    //This version leaves array formatting i.e. entering "2+4*6" would display [2,+,4,*,6] ;good for debugging
    //textViewCalcHistExp1.setText(arrayList.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
private void backspace() {
    if (!arrayList.isEmpty()) {
        // removing the last item from the ArrayList
        arrayList.remove(arrayList.size() - 1);
    }

    String string = textViewCalcHistExp1.getText().toString();
    if (string.length() > 0) {
        // removing the last character from the TextView
        textViewCalcHistExp1.setText(string.substring(0, string.length() - 1));
    }
}
```

You'd also need to make `textViewCalcHistExp1` an instance variable (`arrayList` already is), by declaring it outside `onClick1()`.